# Trying to get separate scripts to load on website

Tags: javascript

I'm not a java script programmer and am way over my head here.

The non-profit I'm volunteering for is using this slideshow (http://dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm) and now wants to add this widget (http://discord.deliriousdrunkards.com/).

The problem is they start conflicting with each other. I know a little bit about Javascript but don't understand how these two scripts are interfering with each other.

If someone can at least point me in a direction as to what might be going on it would be appreciated.

Comment: can you tell us more about the error (conflict)?

Comment: How do we know these links are safe?